# Really need help! how to remove all greyscale from images. (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, web, custom-wordpress-pages

I am really new with this.

Could someone tell me how to remove greyscale from images as seen in website?

> http://tnp.co.th/wp-hank/

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add this CSS rule which resets the grayscale filter:

```
#site .imagebox.style2 .box-image img {
    filter: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Johanese! It works really well. :))